# Trying to use ONVIF webservice with C#, methods without parameters work, others do not with either "bad request" or "closed unexpectedly"

Tags: c#, onvif

The call to GetSystemDateAndTime works.

The call to GetDeviceInformation gives a bad request.

The WSDL is : https://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl

I've tried numerous things and the error message doesn't help... Another application seems to successfully access the camera, but I couldn't figure out how they do it from their source code at : https://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/

But since they can do it I believe there has to be a way... Or at least a way to identify why my code fails and their works, any help is very appreciated.

The code is :

```
        Binding binding;
        HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransportBindingElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
        httpTransportBindingElement.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest;
        binding = new CustomBinding(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10, Encoding.UTF8), httpTransportBindingElement);

        DeviceClient deviceClient = new DeviceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.0.15/onvif/device_service"));

        deviceClient.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
        deviceClient.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName = "username";
        deviceClient.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Password = "password";

        var x = deviceClient.GetSystemDateAndTime();
        var x2 = deviceClient.GetDeviceInformation(out string model, out string firmwareversion, out string serialnumber, out string hardwareId);
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for providing this piece of code. I am new to SOAP and ONVIF. Could you please share where can I get more info on these topics? I didn't know I needed to use CustomBinding etc. What is the source to learn these stuff?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry it's been years since I worked on this. I probably used this project as example https://github.com/AlexBrochu/CameraManager

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this occur if the time between the client and the server are outwith a certain range, usually just a few seconds. Ensure both are using the same NTP server and it might fix the problem.

Some clients get around this by usin the timestamp from the GetSystemDataAndTime call within the requests of other messages to get around this check.

On some cameras it is also possible to turn off the strict checks